# Git Bash with Windows Terminal prints weird characters instead of newline

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I'm on a fresh machine and installed Windows Terminal [Microsoft Store] and Git Bash [latest]. I ran a build script that logs its progress and whenever a newline character appears (maybe others as well?), I get weird characters instead, with everything printed on the same line:

- ```
  ←[1A←[1m> Connecting to Daemon←[m←[22D←[1B←[2A←[1m<←[0;1m-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [73ms]←[m←[38D←[1B←[1m> Evaluating settings←[m←[0K←
  ```

  It should be:

  ```
  Connecting to Daemon
  <-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [73ms]
  Evaluating settings
  ```
- I read about ANSI CON, or something with the registry and the Console keys, but didn't really get anywhere; on another system, everything worked fine, but the setup has multiple differences, including having Cygwin installed, so I cannot be sure if it is the product versions or something else that fixes that.

What is the source of this behavior and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is weird but the solution is simple. In the GitBash `.bashrc` file add the following line at the end

```
export TERM=cygwin
```

Cygwin does not need to be installed for this to work.

Comment: This works but gets rid of colors :(

Comment: Mine seems to work fine, my directories, files and paths are still colored.

Comment: Weird! It could be because I use zsh. I'll dig more and try to see at what step I lose the colors (bash? zsh? oh-my-zsh?). Had the same issue when using the git bash console directly - I had to go in its options and set the terminal to `xterm-256color` to fix it - but I can't do that with Windows Terminal as it needs `TERM=cygwin`

Comment: Maybe because I have explicit colors for `ls`? Although I do get coloring on my current dir path as well. My `.bashrc` has these lines:
`LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;97;40:ow=1;97;40'; export LS_COLORS
export TERM=cygwin`

Comment: Seems to work on git version "2.31.1.windows.1" but not on git version "2.33.0.windows.2"

Comment: could you explain a bit more your answer why those values ?

Comment: It's preference, the configurations are for coloring directories and files.

Answer (score 1):

Still struggle with this. Instead of export TERM=cygwin you can use

```
export TERM=eterm-256color
```

in your .bashrc/.zshrc. This remove the characters and keeps the colors, but gives one error at startup: "/.zshrc:179: can't find terminal definition for eterm-256color".

Let us know if you find anything that work flawlessly.